# contraction of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{**} \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm thinking about the contraction of $\tau : \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{**} \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ can identify with its double dual, then what should other element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{**}$ matched in continuous function $\tau$? Can you give me any hint?

I want to prove the statement that if $\rho: C(X) \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$  is representation and $\tilde{\rho} :B(X) \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is the extension of $\rho$, then $\tilde{\rho}(\phi) = \tau \rho^{**} (\phi)$  so Im thinking about the property of $\tau$. Thank you.

Comment: I believe your question has the potential to be very interesting, but it lacks clarity and I cannot understand exactly what do you mean.  In particular the sentences "can identify with its double dual" and  "matched in continuous function " make no sense to me.

Comment: @Ruy identify with double dual means $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ can be seen as the element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{**}$. So firstly, I want to find the contraction of $\tau : \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{**} \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Sorry for not clarified question.